# Make GIMP 2.8 open in a maximised window and add an "Edit with GIMP" right-click context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, gimp

I'd like to know how I can make GIMP 2.8 (the latest stable release) open in a maximised window. Every time I open it I have to click on the maximise button so that I can see the complete window and frankly it's getting annoying.

I'm using the new Single-Window Mode, which probably helps. I've tried the method of choosing "Maximized" in the Properties of a shortcut, but that just maximises the splash screen, and the actual window is still un-maximised.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. If anybody could help this would be awesome, I use GIMP very often.

By the way, I'd also like to know if anybody knows how I can open most common image files with the "Edit with GIMP" option in the right-click menu. I made some .reg files that would do this with GIMP 2.6, but even after editing the .reg files and using them, if I click the option it will ask me to choose a program to open with. Except for with .gif files, those open properly.

Comment: Now with GIMP 2.10 out, the reg file needs to be adjusted accordingly. Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with GIMP] [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with GIMP\command] @="\"C:\\Program Files\\GIMP 2\\bin\\gimp-2.10.exe\" \"%1\""

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the person who actually compiles GIMP on Windows, the problem is [related to the GTK+ toolkit](http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/14353-love-thread-single-window-mode#message66019). And this makes sense, because GIMP isn't the only linux port to suffer from this annoying problem.

Updating to GIMP 2.8.4 (or higher) will resolve the issue in Single-Window Mode.

Otherwise, you will have to find a third-party program that can automatically maximize windows for you. I am not aware of any free ones but **Actual Window Manager** will do the job. If it's a bit too pricey, you *may* be able to get the same functionality from some of their cheaper programs such as **Actual Window Guard** or **Actual Window Minimizer**.

In regards to your second question, you can use the following registry script to add the 'Edit with GIMP' option to system image types assuming you have GIMP 2.8 installed to the default directory:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with GIMP]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with GIMP\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\GIMP 2\\bin\\gimp-2.8.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a similar registry script before, but apparently it didn't work because it didn't have the double-slashes in the path.
I'll check out some of those maximization programs, too.

Comment: Quick note for those, like me, who had to do a quick refresher on regedit scripts: copy above into text file, save as whatevs.reg, open regedit, file, import, select the .reg file you just saved, job done.

Comment: Now GIMP apparently installs the context menu option by default. I don't see an undo in GIMP's settings. Am I correct in thinking the context menu option is removed via [-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with GIMP]?

Answer (score 2):

To maximize GIMP once it has loaded, you can use [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com) as demonstrated in my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/430863/100787. From there, you can download my [image: icon] **Maximize** executable or compile the script yourself which can then be called from the command line, shortcut, or batch script.

**Example:**

```
Maximize "GNU Image Manipulation Program" "%ProgramFiles%\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.8.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add the "Edit with GIMP" menu with a menu icon (also modified for version 2.10), write this to a file and save it with a `.reg` extension:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with GIMP]
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\GIMP 2\\bin\\gimp-2.10.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with GIMP\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\GIMP 2\\bin\\gimp-2.10.exe\" \"%1\""
```

This will get the GIMP icon to identify the option easily:
[image: Image of the menu with the GIMP icon]

Answer (score 0):

Update for paint.net and useful hint on bottom:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with paint.net]
"Icon"="\"%ProgramFiles%\\paint.net\\PaintDotNet.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with paint.net\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\paint.net\\PaintDotNet.exe\" \"%1\""
```

[And do not forget to set properly Default Photo Viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJyTk.png) otherwise you can have problem with opening of two different edit-apps from context menu as I had.
After I clicked on "Edit with paint.net" via context menu, then default option "Edit" (mspaint.exe) disappeared from context menu.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).