# Add "Edit with Gimp" to Windows context menu

Tags: windows, context-menu, gimp

How can I add an "Edit with Gimp" option to the right-click context menu for image files on my Windows PC?

[image: Edit with GIMP in context menu]

Comment: I don't think this should be marked as a duplicate. The linked duplicate asks two unrelated questions in a single post, with the main topic of "open in a maximized window"

Comment: While there are two sides to the other question it does contain the exact answer that you are asking for. That there is additional information to do an extra task is a bonus.

Comment: As this is essentially the same as the other question I'd be tempted to merge it, except your answer was basically copied from there meaning it would be deleted.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming you have GIMP 2.8 installed to the default directory, you can do this via a registry script [created by David L](https://superuser.com/a/430927/358766).

To add the 'Edit with GIMP' option to system image types, save the following as a `.reg` file and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with GIMP]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\image\shell\Edit with GIMP\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\GIMP 2\\bin\\gimp-2.8.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Still works! W10, gimp 2.10.10